# What Namespace is the Default attribute for properties on UserControls?

Tags: .net, user-controls, properties, default-value

I found half of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234417/custom-property-default-value-net-designer) to my question when searching "what is the attribute to set the default value of a User Control property in the designer where you change it and it bolds".

However the answer neglects to mention the namespace it is in.

Searching through Object Browser yields hundreds of classes/properties with the name Default in it. Google seems to bring up DefaultProperty attribute for ASP.NET, and the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28VS.80%29.aspx) neglects to mention this ability.

Since I can't find the answer on Google, MSDN, Visual Studio, and using VB.NET does not put the namespace it is in by default, I shall put forth the question.

What namespace is it in?

If it's in System.Windows.Forms, what assembly do I need to reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx).

Comment: Well that would make sense why I couldn't find it. The answer had the wrong name, thanks!

Comment: I find myself forgetting where this is on every new project.